# Route Flux do React-Native não funciona

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-router

Já tentei fazer de tudo, quando eu compilei após ter instalado o Router Flux, apareceu um erro falando que estava necessitando de alguns módulos, como react-native-gesture-handler e react-native-screens  depois que eu fiz a instalação deles compilou, quando executei o comando react-native start porém o App não abre já dei RELOAD e nada, aparece a seguinte mensagem que mostra na imagem... já mudei varias partes do meu código porém nada, acontece o mesmo erro.

[image: Print do erro que aparece ao executar react-native start e da um reload no app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente o `<Router>` não aceita vários componentes `<Scene>` de uma só vez, tenta envolver esses componentes no componente `<Stack>`, não esquece de importar ele.

```
<Router>
    <Stack key="root">
        <Scene >
        ...
    </Stack>
</Router>
```

Comment: Obrigado man! <3